# Record Audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to record and play audio in html using MediaSourceExtensions and MediaRecorder.

here is my code:

```
async function recordAudio()
{
    let mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    let MediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(MediaStream);
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    let chunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.start(400);
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("audio/ogg;codecs=opus");
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => 
    {
        sourceBuffer.appendSourceBuffer(e.data);
    };
}
```

here are the errors I'm getting(on Firefox):

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: MediaSource.addSourceBuffer: Type not supported in MediaSource.

Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/ogg;codecs=opus.
```

what I'm going for is for the voice to be played almost immediately/400ms after the input but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I changed the mimeType to "audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"" which is apparently the only supported format, that solved the first problem but now the browser is giving me this error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable (line 11).
```

Comment: Have you tried using a supported format?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: "audio/ogg;codecs=opus" is not supported. What browser are you using?

Comment: I searched for "mediasourceextension supported formats" but couldn't find much.